# Multiple error info emails to admin if query fails using debug_backtrace()

Tags: php, mysql

My application is used by 5000 people. Its a medium sized application. I am using a class which takes care of my queries like escaping variables, doing the clean up, etc. I have a function in the class which is responsible for executing queries. So all the queries from any page needs to call this function execute the query.

```
function runQuery() {
    //prepare and other lines here 

    //execute
    $run = $query->execute($args);

    if(!$run) {
       //debug_backtrace() and mail the admin
    }

}
```

Everything is working fine. One of the page in my application is "Work" and usually most of the employees are in this page all the time. The only problem is if 100 users are accessing the application, and if something goes wrong with one of the query, i get 100 mails about the same error. I need only 1 email. How can i manage this ? I am worried if a 1000 users are accessing together, my outlook will go mad. The probability of triggering an error is less but still, i want to catch them.

Answer (score 0):

Their is no way you can achieve this. Your mail function is in the wrong location. One solution is You can use filters in your outlook and block emails which repeat.